# How to create an object from 2 arrays of same length

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to create an object from 2 arrays.

```
var arr1 = ["2000", "10003", "1234000", "44444444", "9999", "11", "11", "22", "123"];
var arr2 = [2, 4, 10, 32, 36, 2, 2, 4, 6];
```

I used a for loop to populate the object:

```
var obj= {};

for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) { 
    obj[arr1[i]] = arr2[i]; 
}
```

Result:

```
[object Object] {
  10003: 4,
  11: 2,
  123: 6,
  1234000: 10,
  2000: 2,
  22: 4,
  44444444: 32,
  9999: 36
}
```

It does create the object based on my 2 arrays, but omit 1 value that is a duplicate in the arrays. I don't want to exclude them. What could be the trick to include ALL the array element in my object? The result is not even in the same order as the original arrays...

Thank you!

Comment: Object cannot have duplicate keys

Comment: use array as value ( in case there is multiple )

Comment: What do want as a result of this operation?

Comment: I would like to have at least this: [object Object] {
  10003: 4,
  11: 2, 
  11:2,
  123: 6,
  1234000: 10,
  2000: 2,
  22: 4,
  44444444: 32,
  9999: 36
}

Comment: can you share what do you want as result. I mean give us the result.

Comment: as @MaheerAli said you can't have duplicate keys in the same object.

Comment: Yep! Now I know the reason of the disappearance! got to find a solution to work around that then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

populate the values into array if that could be a workaround for you..

```
var obj= [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) { 
  var obj1 ={};
  obj1[arr1[i]] = arr2[i];           
  obj.push(obj1);
}
```